# '400 Bad request' - Google not redirecting back correctly after Authentication using DotNetOpenAuth and PhoneGap ChildBrowser plugin

Tags: cordova, dotnetopenauth, childbrowser

I'm working on a simple implementation of **[THIS DotNetOpenAuth  tutorial](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/help/programmatic-openid-relying-party/)**.

On a regular browser such as Chrome, Firefox and IE it works fine. But when I call this "google_login.aspx" page from the PhoneGap childBrowser plugin It fails.

Failure happens in the form of a `400 -Bad Request - Invalid URL` ***after*** the user has put his credentials into Google.

When Google tries to redirect back to my site, **Google trying to use a bad url** which looks like this:

```
https://myurl.com/(F(8g0QkKd61D6yBbN2pkuZwAXOTGChqwruytA0LCC_nZko2mXgddbDhT3nXCj3XWVwOSkyfNGENHtctVXbnAyFQcj344Cai3rrkKKO_SNM_laGIqIPN2pkSBJQQYc98T0qv_gZbm3R8Qufry7u-HLAAT_RfVpMtpbCM6sw-FLPuxxHUETRHjd8lA9DR7LKIfkMYYinZU_qLduO02f012wZ2feVi8XW479WOvrWCr_rHFAxPNEQFurrJO1rxGs1LUFzTZ4pNlgpm4LwHrv7lTtK5-adDKbQJXzFrjEAG22pNxGfKpesHNsV-m88zp20w70FtF56wppLfzadNgq7cPDlb3hIwbsA-JGI1he8low8_KWDNZev5RqtX8cPtQKpFIL0))/Default.aspx
```

Instead of this:

```
https://myurl.com/Default.aspx
```

This only happens on the *PhoneGap childBrowser plugin*, other browsers take me to the right place.

After getting the `400 bad request` error I can manually browse to my homepage and it shows that I am in fact signed in, and that **the simple redirect back from Google is what failed**.

Anyone know how of a fix or possible workaround to my problem?

## Solution:

I had to specify the `returnToURL` parameter in the `OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest` :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it may be ASP.NET's cookieless session support feature.  If your failing scenario is one where session cookies are rejected, and if enabled in the web.config file, I believe ASP.NET will essentially store the cookie in your URLs instead, creating a kind of virtual path.  Obviously something is going wrong with this though.  I suggest you isolate the problem by:

1. [Turn on DotNetOpenAuth logging](http://tinyurl.com/dnoalogs)
2. Collect a [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) trace of the entire login attempt

...to figure out where this stray path is coming from.

Comment: Good suggestion... I'll post back with results. (+1)

Comment: No errors but specifying the `returnToURL` parameter in the `OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest` worked.

Comment: You'll get this problem with the iOS web browser control (which is used by PhoneGap)... IIS/Casini think that it can't handle cookies, and do the url thing instead, but you can force cookie use in the web.config file.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem:

1. Add the `App_Browsers` ASP.NET folder to your project if it doesn't already exist (right-click on the project, click Add -> Add ASP.NET Folder -> App.Browsers
2. Add a file called `generic.browser` to the App.Browsers folder
3. Replace any automatically generated code in the generic.browser file with:

   ```
   <browsers>
       <browser refID="Default">
           <capabilities>
               <capability name="cookies" value="true" />
           </capabilities>
       </browser>
   </browsers>
   ```

The problem occurs with reasonable frequency on iOS devices such as iPad and iOS when running Forms Authentication. The user will receive the error: **Bad Request - Invalid URL. HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.**

Comment: I had tried this, and did not work. What did work was explicitly specifying the `returnToURL` parameter in `OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest`